# Compiling libjpeg on Windows using cygwin?

Tags: c, windows, cygwin, libjpeg

Which is the best way to compile libjpeg on a Windows machine? Should I use Microsoft Visual Studio or can I use something else like Cygwin?

Note: when I use Cygwin and copy `makefile.vc` to `Makefile`, `jconfig.vc` to `jconfig.h` and run this sample code: http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~junaed/code/libjpeg_sample.tar.gz

then the compiler produces the following errors:

```
$ gcc main.c
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccwChyeY.o:main.c:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error'
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccwChyeY.o:main.c:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateDecompress'
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccwChyeY.o:main.c:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_src'
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccwChyeY.o:main.c:(.text+0xa9): undefined reference to `jpeg_read_header'
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccwChyeY.o:main.c:(.text+0xb7): undefined reference to `jpeg_start_decompress'
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccwChyeY.o:main.c:(.text+0x11b): undefined reference to `jpeg_read_scanlines'
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccwChyeY.o:main.c:(.text+0x178): undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_decompress'
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccwChyeY.o:main.c:(.text+0x186): undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_decompress'
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccwChyeY.o:main.c:(.text+0x1f6): undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error'
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccwChyeY.o:main.c:(.text+0x21a): undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateCompress'
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccwChyeY.o:main.c:(.text+0x22f): undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_dest'
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccwChyeY.o:main.c:(.text+0x269): undefined reference to `jpeg_set_defaults'
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccwChyeY.o:main.c:(.text+0x27f): undefined reference to `jpeg_start_compress'
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccwChyeY.o:main.c:(.text+0x2c7): undefined reference to `jpeg_write_scanlines'
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccwChyeY.o:main.c:(.text+0x2e5): undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_compress'
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccwChyeY.o:main.c:(.text+0x2f3): undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_compress'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What does the makefile look like? Does it have crazy VC stuff that gnu tools don't like?

Comment: http://codepad.org/NvlYnIm4

Comment: Makefiles are not the same across vendors. Does copying makefile.vc to Makefile usually work??

Comment: Configuring the software using one of the supplied jconfig and makefile files
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
If you have one of these systems, you can just use the provided configuration
files:
Makefile jconfig file System and/or compiler
makefile.vc jconfig.vc Windows NT/95, MS Visual C++
Copy the proper jconfig file to jconfig.h and the makefile to Makefile (or
whatever your system uses as the standard makefile name).  For more info see
the appropriate system-specific hints section near the end of this file.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you just want the `.dll` it is already compiled.

[`https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=libjpeg&arch=x86_64`](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=libjpeg&arch=x86_64)